# What causes very long initial visit load times intermittently?

Tags: caching, performance

I'm working on what is basically a one page site externally:

- **http://drupals.badgerfort.com**.

There's very little to it. But I'm getting reports that it's sometimes loading so slow to the point that a couple refreshes are required to get it to load on first visit.  Now as this is such a small site, virtually every significant module is turned off.

I mean Update is off, Views is off, Date is off and on and on. In addition to that the few graphics are optimized. There's no external content integrated that could be causing it to hang that I can think of. CSS and JS are being aggregated. Caching is off, but it is a one page site, so on initial visit I wouldn't think caching would provide any advantage.

What are some of the potential causes of an issue like this?

Comment: Have you turned caching on to confirm that's not the issue?

Comment: Well... I have had trouble reproducing it on my machine and connection.  But it's been reported twice. I always clear my own cache before loading the site to try, but I haven't caught it yet.  So if I did, I wouldn't easily know the result... this is a problem in general for this.

Comment: Though my understanding of caching is that on initial visit (which is what I am worried about) it should have no effect at all.  To be cached the data must have been loaded once.

Comment: It depends who's initial visit you mean...say an anonymous user hits your page when the caches are empty, and caching is on. The expensive processing to build the HTML is done, and the result is cached. Then a new anon user comes along for their first visit. They will be served the cached version of the page, no expensive build required. If you have caching off, that processing needs to be done every time for every visitor, whereas with it on, it only happens once for all anonymous users when the data isn't in cache. Make more sense?

Comment: Ah, yes that does make a lot more sense now! Thank you for taking the time to explain.  I will enable. There is no good reason not to.  I was under the misunderstanding the caching performance refers to took place on a per visitor basis. But I guess the browser handles caching resources like that anyway, so I'm not sure why I thought that.

Comment: I turned views back on (doesn't seem to have alone affected things significantly in my usage) and created a report to check the load times of external traffic. Now I can watch and see how it performs I suppose.

Comment: do you have Cron set to run? I have found this can cause this sort of behaviour in certain set ups

Comment: @Geoff, do you mean that having cron set to run (or having cron set to run at certain times) can cause the behavior or that failing to do so can? 

I have cron set to run every 3 hours as is the default. If it is the case that cron's running can cause it, should I simply set it to run less often?

Comment: Cron runs during the first access of the page after a certain amount of time has passed (3 hours for you now) - so it delays the user's access to the page while it runs - if that particular cron is running a lot of items, or the server is lagged at that particular time, it could take considerable time for cron to finish, making it seem random. If you increase the time, the number of items generally increases, but it depends on the site - you can test by turning cron off completely for a few weeks, just remember to manually run it once a day or so for maintenance, but your users wont run it

Comment: @Geoff actually, this shouldn't happen that way. Cron should be started at end of the request, not delaying user access significantly. It's called in `drupal_page_footer()`, after, well, everything else. Most important - after call to `ob_flush()`, so data should be sent to browser before it starts. Of course, browser's throbber may keep spinning for some time - bot that's not what users reported, is it?

Comment: @Mołot I have found otherwise, testing with timestamps, that cron while running at the end of the render cycle, still slows a page's load to the end user... I don't know that that's what happening here, just something I have observed in some situations, that by disabling cron, the problem no longer appears

Comment: @Molot: No, "it wasn't coming up; I had to refresh a couple times." Thanks both for the input. I was under the impression that only poormanscron ran at time of request.  I didn't know regular ol' cron did.  Why, actually? Crontabs are files being parsed and enacted by a daemon over on the server that is periodically scanning I thought? Is that an incorrect conception?

Comment: This may sound odd, but I was able to resolve a very similar issue by switching from disabling dblog and switching to syslog. That and making sure cron was running every few minutes with caching for anonymous users made a huge difference in that 'initial page load'.

Answer (score 0):

If users experience very long response time for initial visit, but then next visits are fast - then it definitely could be related to the cron (as suggested by Geoff).

Here is a quote from official [cron documentation](https://www.drupal.org/cron):

> It [internal cron] works by checking at the end of each Drupal request to see when cron last ran and, if it has been too long, processing the cron tasks as part of that request. The two down-sides are (1) cron tasks will only run when Drupal is processing requests; and (2) the 'weight' (processing and memory) of running the cron tasks will be added to some arbitrary unknown page request, which may slow down those requests, and has the potential to exceed memory limits on a complex site.

To prevent this, [configure external cron job](https://www.drupal.org/node/23714) that will trigger Drupal cron jobs more often that 3 hours (my suggestion is to run external cron every hour).

In addition you can configure internal cron to run less often by configuring it here /admin/config/system/cron.